# Open new workbook, and run macro, using button

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that runs a large multitude of macros, all based on which button is clicked.

I need one of the macro to open a new workbook, and import two files into the workbook (that part I can do).

**The second part is that I need it to run a particular macro, in the new workbook. The macro would be stored in the original workbook**.

I've seen some suggestions that I need to use `APPLICATION.RUN`, which has the parameters of having to choose a workbook and name of the routine.

Does this method work?

Assuming it does:

For the workbook, do I need to **specify the file path**, or just the workbook name?

For the macro, do I need to **make the macro public**?

Do I need to **specify the module** it is in?

Are there any other parameters I need to specify to get this method to work?

Is there **another method that might work**, if `APPLICATION.RUN` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is :

`Application.Run "'FileName.xlsm'!MacroName", "Parameters"`

You **don't need to specify the path** if your workbook is already open, you **don't need to specify the module** as you can't have doubloons names for different procedures, and **there are no other parameters needed**.

The **procedure doesn't need to be public** (let me know if it does), and for alternative methods in VBA, there is none (as the `Call` method only work in the same workbook), but there are some in VB if this doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very short example that you can adapt:

```
Sub demo()
    Dim Original As Workbook
    Dim Created As Workbook
    Set Original = ThisWorkbook

    '   create a new workbook

    Workbooks.Add
    Set Created = ActiveWorkbook

    '    go back

    Original.Activate

    'make a change in the newly created workbook

    Created.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "whatever"

    '   save the newly created workbook

    Created.Save
    Created.Close

End Sub
```